# How do you send workers to a friend on Tiny Towers?

Tags: tiny-tower

I don't know how to send workers to someone else on Tiny Towers. I sent a request to my sister but she doesn't know how to send them to me... Can someone help me out!

Comment: How do you request a bitizen?

Answer (score 2):

`Menu > Bitizens > Select which Bitizen to send > Select "SEND TO FRIEND"`

the button is located just under the Bitizen stats area